# Method of interpolation and solving for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$1.43=6-\frac{2}{x}-2.$$
How can I make $x$ the subject and solve for $x$. This is the method of interpolation and we asked to solve for $x$ its very complicated since $x$ is in the denominator.

I think I wil bring the $2$ on the denominator to the other side but it will violates the BODMAS rule.

I tried simplifying the right-hand side by computing $6-2=4$. Then $\dfrac{4×1}{x-2}=1.43$ but it is still difficult, since the $x$ is still in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to solve $1.43=6-\frac{2}{x}-2$, we proceed to subtract $6$ from both sides and also add $2$ to both sides. Then we have $1.43-6+2=6-\frac{2}{x}-2$, and after cancelling we get $-2.57=-\frac{2}{x}$. Multiplying by $x$ on bith sides and dividing by $-2.57$, we have $x=\frac{2}{2.57}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1.43=4-\dfrac{2}{x}$$
$$4-1.43=\dfrac{2}{x}$$
$$2.57=\dfrac{2}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{x}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2.57}$$
$$x=\dfrac{2}{2.57}$$